# Enable Wake on LAN Network-Wide

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan

We're looking into enabling Wake-On-LAN at my workplace, and we tested it on my PC. It works, but I had to first go into the settings on the network card (within Windows) and enable it. Is there a way that I can enable this setting across our network, through Group Policy or something?

[image]

These are the settings that I had to enable (the bottom 2.) I'm running Windows 10, but most of our environment is still on Windows 7.

Comment: It can be done using GP, but note some machine require a BIOS setting change as well. Search for "wake on lan via group policy" to get some ideas.